# What is the correct way to generate multi-word reference fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rails generate model product name:string twoWord:string twoWordRef:references
```

produces the following migration file

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :twoWord
      t.references :twoWordRef, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :products, :twoWordRefs
  end
end
```

I thought that field names were supposed to be snake case, not camel case, yet `rails generate model` is producing camel case field names in the migration file. I think I am following the examples on my generate command.

I am also finding issues later on when I try to update via reference where rails assumes the foreign key is in snake case and can't find my foreign key in the table.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: refereces should have a model like `user_profile:references` where `UserProfile` is a model

Comment: Thanks Rajarshi.  I'll go back and redo all of my field names now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rails automatically generate the database tables in snake case. For example if your model is `TestModel` corresponding table in database will be `test_models`. However same is not the case for attributes.

Do this instead:

```
rails generate model product name:string two_word:string two_word_ref:references
```

**Update**

This is completely out of scope for what OP asked, but I thought sharing this might be helpful if you are starting Rails. Rails uses a few conventions when naming models and tables (like singular name for model and plural for table). For this it uses `ActiveSupport::Inflector` module.

> The Inflector transforms words from singular to plural, class names to
>   table names, modularized class names to ones without, and class names
>   to foreign keys. The default inflections for pluralization,
>   singularization, and uncountable words are kept in inflections.rb.

You can use its [classify](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify) and [tableize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-tableize) methods to validate corresponding names. Eg:

```
"test_models".classify
# => "TestModel"

"TestModel".tableize
# => "test_models"
```

Comment: Thanks Shivam. That answers my question and I believe it will solve my problem.